# Google Sheets allow access to a webapp

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a very specific situation, I'm building a service (**addon**) with google app scripts and there is a functionality I want to try but I've been struggling with the documentation.

I'll build and deploy a webapp, that will be accessible by anyone, a simple form.  And I want this form to write a row on a google sheet, the deal is that **I won't know the sheets ID**, I'm building an **add-on that will allow any sheet to be accesible to the webapp** and recive the post or get variables and use them.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of Add-on is this?  Spreadsheet?  The Add-on is associated with the document (Spreadsheet) that it is installed in.  You can get the spreadsheet with `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.  If that isn't the case, then you'll need to provide a file picker to the user, so they can pick the spreadsheet that they want to use.  [Link to Google File Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/)

Comment: Your question is considered "Off Topic" because it is to general.  Stack Overflow is not for general advice.  You can join the Apps Script community  [Link to Apps Script group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  and the Add-ons group [Link](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sandy, yes it will be a spreadsheet add-on, my problem is how do I tell the spreadsheet where the add-on is installed to allow access to a stand alone webapp?

Comment: The URL of the stand alone web app is always the same.  There are two versions of the web app URL, the "dev" and the "exec".   "dev" is the development version.  "exec" is the "production" version.  Either "dev" or "exec" will be on the end of the web app URL.  You can provide a link to the web app in the HTML of a sidebar or dialog box.  You can't open a browser link from server side code, but you can make an HTTPS GET or POST request to `doGet()` or `doPost()` from servers side code with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Sandy I kinda had the same idea;

First I build an add-on that would allow the sheet to be written by the webApp and would provide a GET variable with the sheets ID.

```
function useWebApp() {
   var sheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
   var openFile = DriveApp.getFileById(sheetID)
   openFile.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("https://  [WEBAPPLINK]  /exec?sheet="+sheetID );
 }
```

Second, as suggested, I build the WebApp and used the provided HTTP GET variable to write on the sheet.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var targetSheet = e.parameter.sheet;
  var label = app.createLabel('Parameter value sheet:'+e.parameter.sheet;
  app.add(label);

  //insertSheetLine(e.parameter.sheet);    //test to insert rows directly

 PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('targetSheet', e.parameter.sheet);  //define a global variable in the script
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

This way one can avoid the OAuth deal as long as the webapp is published to impersonate the owner. With that in mind anyone can use it and write in the sheet w/o registration.
The main idea will be to publish an Add-On with the useWebApp method installable so it will work on any sheet.

Thanks again Sandy